# Adding jQuery media query to a# scrollTop

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I'm trying to add a javascript media query like this

**JS**

```
if(width <= 1024), scroll = 480;
    scroll = width > 768 ? 360 : 240;
```

to something like this.

EDIT - I'm trying to add a variable to the the a#content based on screen width. ie: if 1024 = scrollTop 500, 768 = 360, 320 = 200

**JS**

```
$("a[href='#content']").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("body").scrollTop() == 0 ? 360 : 0
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

Any help or advice would be greatly accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple scrollTop**

Try this:

```
$("a[href='#content']").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $width = $(window).width(),
        $scrollTop;
    
    if($width > 1024){
        $scrollTop = 500;
    } else if($width > 768){
        $scrollTop = 360;
    } else {
        $scrollTop = 0;
    }

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$scrollTop},800);
});
```

This gets the screen width on each click, assigns the pixel height from top you want, and animates to it appropriately. You can modify the widths in the `if` statement as desired, as well as the animation speed, but should work out.

[jsFiddle as example](http://jsfiddle.net/CwMRk/1/) (scroll down the window to see the link, its `1000px` down to show the animation of `scrollTop`)

**Toggling scrollTop** (since you asked)

There are many ways to toggle between the assigned value or not, but I always prefer using classes:

```
$("a[href='#content']").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $width = $(window).width(),
        $this = $(this),
        $scrollTop = 0;

    if($this.hasClass('Top0')){
        $this.removeClass('Top0');
    } else {
        $this.addClass('Top0');
        if($width > 1024){
            $scrollTop = 500;
        } else if($width > 768){
            $scrollTop = 360;
        }
    }

    $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$scrollTop},800);
});
```

This is a little bit more involved. First, the `$scrollTop` variable is set to 0 on each click. Then it checks to see whether the link has the class `Top0`, and if it does then it just removes the class, keeping the 0 value. If the class does not exist already, it will add the class and check if it matches the other criteria, first `> 1024` and then `> 768`. If it matches either of these items it will assign the appropriate value, otherwise `$scrollTop` will again remain 0. Very lightweight and encapsulated.

One other thing to note is that I added `.stop()` before the animation; since your animation is now being toggled and possibly fired repeatedly, you don't want the animation to queue its execution. `.stop()` will prevent this from happening. I also cached `$(this)` when doing this since there were several references to it; not necessary, just good practice.

Comment: Animating scroll top on body only doesnt work in firefox. Also, animating html onle doesnt work in chrome. You need to animate the HTML and the body if you want it to work in firefox and chrome.

Comment: your edit actually makes things more confusing. are you saying that when u click on the `a`, you want to do something to `content`?

Comment: Sorry for confusing things. Clicking content should scroll to top and slide down 360px. However I'm trying to add a variable of if 1024 slide down 500, if 768 slide down 360

Comment: i gotchya, modified my answer again for what i think u want. jsFiddle is also provided.

Comment: Great!! Is there a way to toggle the #content button to switch between scroll to top and scroll 500?

Comment: there are a lot of ways to toggle, this is just the first thing that came to mind. before someone chimes in: yes, you can use `.toggleClass()`, but when there is computation involved (no matter how simple) it sometimes takes too long to add/remove the class and creates duplicates.